# By click of the button the same form is added under that form but how can i get the value of the number of times it getting printed &store it in table

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

by click of the button the same form is added under that form but how can i get the value of the number of times it getting printed &store it in table. How can I insert the data into table if the user add more experiences from model. On the click of the button the value in the value field should increment too and how can I enter if the user add any number of experiences so how can I enter the data in the table. I am inserting this data in table in row wise fashion in table

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="addexperience">
  <button type="button" class="btn-primary"  style="float:right;" onclick="addexperience()">Add work experience</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="1experience" id="1experience" value="<?php $i = 1; ?>">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>If yes, fill the following table</label>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="status">
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="1" <?php sel($student_experience['status'], '1'); ?>>Current</option>
     <option value="0" <?php sel($student_experience['status'], '0'); ?>>Past</option>
    </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Designation</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="designation" value="<?php echo esc_output($student_experience['designation']);?>">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Duration</label>
    <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="duration" value="<?php echo esc_output($student_experience['duration']);?>">  
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Employer</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="employer" value="<?php echo esc_output($student_experience['employer']);?>">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  function addexperience(){
    var i = $('#1experience').val();
    i++; 
    $('#addexperience').append('<div class="col-md-3"> <label>Status</label> <select class="form-control" name="status'+i+'">'+
                          '<option value="">Select</option>'+
                          '<option value="Current">Current</option>'+
                          '<option value="Past">Past</option> </select> </div>'+

                      '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                        '<label>Designation</label>'+
                        '<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="designation'+i+'">'+
                      '</div>'+

                      '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                        '<label>Duration</label>'+
                        '<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="duration'+i+'">'+  
                      '</div>'+

                      '<div class="col-md-3">'+
                        '<label>Employer</label>'+
                        '<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="employer'+i+'">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>');
                     

    $(function () {
      $('#1experience').val(i);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: `$(function () { ...});` adds code to be executed when the document has finished loading. But you are only adding that inside the function `addexperience`, which will be called way after loading has already finished. So what you have put in there, will never execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the HTML slightly in both the initial page display and within the javascript function so that the newly added items are grouped within a single container(`div`) and the initial elements are similarly grouped and a name assigned to the immediate ancestor of the initially displayed elements ( here I chose `data-id='receiver'` ) then this matter of deducing the number of times the elements have been added becomes a matter of counting the child elements within the common parent - `querySelectorAll` being useful here though no doubt jQuery has a concise method to do this too.

With that said though if you were to use the array syntax form form element names, such as `designation[]` or `duration[]` when the form is submitted you will have access to each element as an array in PHP ( or other backend language ) which will also, as a byproduct, reveal that same number of elements. Using the array syntax means you do not need to try to keep track of this number within the client

```js
function addexperience() {
  let i=document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="receiver"] > div').length;
  
  $('[data-id="receiver"]').append('<div><div class="col-md-3"> <label>Status</label> <select class="form-control" name="status' + i + '">' +
    '<option value="">Select</option>' +
    '<option value="Current">Current</option>' +
    '<option value="Past">Past</option> </select> </div>' +

    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    '<label>Designation</label>' +
    '<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="designation' + i + '">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    '<label>Duration</label>' +
    '<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="duration' + i + '">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    '<label>Employer</label>' +
    '<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="employer' + i + '">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div></div>');


    alert(i);
    document.querySelector('input[name="duplicates"]').value=i;
    
    fetch( location.href, {method:'post',body:'total='+i})
      .then(r=>r.text())
      .then(text=>{
        alert(text)
      })
}
```

```css
[data-id='receiver']{border:1px solid red;margin:1rem;padding:1rem;}
[data-id='receiver'] > div{margin:1rem;border:1px solid black;padding:0.5rem}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12" id="addexperience">

    <button type="button" class="btn-primary" style="float:right;" onclick="addexperience()">Add work experience</button>

    <div data-id='receiver' class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label>If yes, fill the following table</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>Status</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="status">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php sel($student_experience[ 'status'], '1'); ?>>Current</option>
                    <option value="0" <?php sel($student_experience[ 'status'], '0'); ?>>Past</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>Designation</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="designation" value="<?php echo esc_output($student_experience['designation']);?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>Duration</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="duration" value="<?php echo esc_output($student_experience['duration']);?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label>Employer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employer" value="<?php echo esc_output($student_experience['employer']);?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- additional content inserted here within common parent -->
    </div>
</div>


<input type='hidden' name='duplicates' />
```

Comment: This working fine , but now how can i store the number of forms printed in a variable and then use that variable to store the entered value in my table

Comment: You want that number in PHP??

Comment: I just added some extra html (hidden input) and basic ajax function. It is not clear when you need this count or where. In PHP if you used the array syntax you would have that count within the POSTed data. Otherwise the variable `i` which gets alerted is the number you want

Comment: yes i wangt that number in php every time the user clicks the button the counter should increase, at default the counter should be one and as the user clicks the counnter should increase every time the user clicks the button

Comment: You need then to use `ajax` - and I added the `fetch` routine which *you* will need to adapt and process.